# Reloading TableView from CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

Does anyone have idea how to reload TableView that's inside of `CollectionViewCustomCell?` I have an `IBOutlet` of that `Table` and the only way to access that `Table` is inside *`cellForItemAtIndexPath`* method where I can access my `CollectionViewCustomCell` and through that access the `Table`.

```
cell.tableViewInsideOfCollectionViewCell.reloadData()
```

But this only works on the first load, when I change `CollectionView` source it will not reload `TableView`.

If you need anymore info, please ask!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the cell using `collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath)` method. Then cast it to the type of cell that contains the tableView. Now you have access to that cells properties and can reload the tableView.

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: , section: )) as? CustomCellWithTableView else { return }
cell.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JustinM